# use case diagrams - for two application (Software requirements specification document)

Tags: use-case, srs

I'm writing an SRS document for two application that serve two user of a restaurant "Reservation system " . One for the manager and the other for the client . 
I'm wondering if i should separate them into different systems when i draw the use case diagram ?

or since they serve the same system i should put them in the same system block ?

--

+If you guys know any subtitles i should cover in the SRS document please post them .
I've only covered the requirements and the use cases.

Comment: And when i draw the interface does't have to be designed or just to show off it's functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRSs are typically developed during the first stages of "Requirements Development," which is the initial product development phase in which information is gathered about what requirements are needed--and not.

You probably will be a member of the SRS team (if not, ask to be), which means SRS development will be a collaborative effort for a particular project. Several standards organizations (including the IEEE) have identified nine topics that must be addressed when designing and writing an SRS:

1. Interfaces
2. Functional Capabilities
3. Performance Levels
4. Data Structures/Elements
5. Safety
6. Reliability
7. Security/Privacy
8. Quality
9. Constraints and Limitations

A sample of a basic SRS outline

1. Introduction
   1.1 Purpose
   1.2 Document conventions
   1.3 Intended audience
   1.4 Additional information
   1.5 Contact information/SRS team members
   1.6 References
2. Overall Description
   2.1 Product perspective
   2.2 Product functions
   2.3 User classes and characteristics
   2.4 Operating environment
   2.5 User environment
   2.6 Design/implementation constraints
   2.7 Assumptions and dependencies
3. External Interface Requirements
   3.1 User interfaces
   3.2 Hardware interfaces
   3.3 Software interfaces
   3.4 Communication protocols and interfaces
4. System Features
   4.1 System feature A
   4.1.1 Description and priority
   4.1.2 Action/result
   4.1.3 Functional requirements
   4.2 System feature B
5. Other Nonfunctional Requirements
   5.1 Performance requirements
   5.2 Safety requirements
   5.3 Security requirements
   5.4 Software quality attributes
   5.5 Project documentation
   5.6 User documentation
6. Other Requirements
   Appendix A: Terminology/Glossary/Definitions list
   Appendix B: To be determined

about the question,the manager and client are actor of a same system. So you should use one system for your project.